# Validate country calling from API

Tags: javascript, validation, api, country

```
<div class='input1'>
                    <select name="gender" class="gender" id="gender">
                        <option value="">Gender</option>
                        <option value="male">Male</option>
                        <option value="female">Female</option>
                    </select>
</div>
```

**js**

```
reg_gender = /(male|female)/;
      if(form.gender.value == "" && (!reg_gender.test(form.gender.value)) ) {
          alert("Please select gender!");
          form.gender.focus();
          return false;
      }
```

> EDITTED

How should I validate country using the method similar to gender? However, my country is not hardcoded. It is calling from an api. 
[image]

Comment: Just change value of Gender(first option) to blank, it should work <option value="">Gender</option>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make simple change to your *HTML*:

```
<div class='input1'>
   <select id="gender" name="gender" class="gender">
     <option value="">Gender</option> <!-- make change value="" -->
     <option value="male">Male</option>
      <option value="female">Female</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

Also add some line of codes in your *javascript*:

```
reg_gender = /(male|female)/;
if(form.gender.value == "" && (!reg_gender.test(form.gender.value)) ) {
    alert("Please select gender!");
    form.gender.focus();
    return false;
}
```

This expression `/(male|female)/` check if value is either `male` or `female`

Comment: Hi! I've found that this method help alot! However, how should i validate country using the method you've mentioned above? @Shaz